# 4x3 grid with two items double height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create 4x3 grid with two items double height.

```css
.grida {
 width:540px;
 display: grid;
 row-gap: 14px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 120px);
 justify-content:space-evenly;
 align-content: space-evenly;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #444;
}

.card {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: #555;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 150%;
 height:68px;
}

.a {
 grid-row: auto / span 2;
}

.g {
 grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class='grida'>
  <div class="card a">A</div>
  <div class="card b">B</div>
  <div class="card c">C</div>
  <div class="card d">D</div>
  <div class="card e">E</div>
  <div class="card f">F</div>
  <div class="card g">G</div>
  <div class="card h">H</div>
  <div class="card i">I</div>
  <div class="card j">J</div>
</div>
```

Why are there empty blocks?
I want `a` and `g` to be double height.
Any help?

Comment: look , if it helps ihave created one element row double, and other column double : http://jsfiddle.net/1853602k/

Comment: Just add `height: 160px;` to `.a`. `.a {
    height: 160px;
    grid-row: auto / span 2;
}`

Comment: You are setting a height on class `.card` that's why `grid-row` doesn't work. See my answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`grid-row` doesn't work because you are setting a height on the `card` divs. In order to adjust the "height" of `card` divs, I did a trick using padding. Do this:

```css
.grida {
 width:540px;
 display: grid;
 row-gap: 14px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 120px);
 justify-content:space-evenly;
 align-content: space-evenly;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #444;
}

.card {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: #555;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 150%;
 padding: 30px 5px
}

.a, .g {
 grid-row: auto / span 2 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='grida'>
  <div class="card a">A</div>
  <div class="card b">B</div>
  <div class="card c">C</div>
  <div class="card d">D</div>
  <div class="card e">E</div>
  <div class="card f">F</div>
  <div class="card g">G</div>
  <div class="card h">H</div>
  <div class="card i">I</div>
  <div class="card j">J</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered but using `grid-auto-rows:68px` might be the less hacky solution.

```css
    .grida {
        width:540px;
        display: grid;
        row-gap: 14px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 120px);
        justify-content:space-evenly;
        align-content: space-evenly;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
        /*setting the height of automatically/implicitly created rows*/
        grid-auto-rows:68px;
    }

    .card {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: #555;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 150%;
        /*height:68px;*/

    }

    .a,.g {
        grid-row: auto / span 2;
    }
```

```html
<div class='grida'>
    <div class="card a">A</div>
    <div class="card b">B</div>
    <div class="card c">C</div>
    <div class="card d">D</div>
    <div class="card e">E</div>
    <div class="card f">F</div>
    <div class="card g">G</div>
    <div class="card h">H</div>
    <div class="card i">I</div>
    <div class="card j">J</div>
</div>
```